# C# says I didn't define something when I did?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

```
MessageReceivedEventArgs e;
sendMessage(e);
```

That's my code. I have no idea why it says this error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'e'

Comment: The error quite patently says something other than what you say in your title.

Answer (score 7):

"defined" and "assigned" are 2 different things.  You defined the variable but did not assign it.

"Define" (or "declare") just means that you specified there exists a variable by this name (and type).

Assigning it means actually giving it a value.  Right now you're saying there's a variable called `e` of type `MessageReceivedEventArgs' but that variable doesn't hold anything.

Answer (score 4):

It's complaining that you're using it be for assigning a value, not that it's undefined.  You need to create an instance of `MessageReceivedEventArgs` before using it

```
MessageReceivedEventArgs e = new MessageReceivedEventArgs();
sendMessage(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You **declared** the MessageReceivedEventArgs but you didn't assign something to it

Answer (score 0):

You declared but didn't created, instantiated the variable so it has no value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MessageReceivedEventArgs e = new MessageReceivedEventArgs();
sendMessage(e)
```

Just like it said: you need to initialize your variables before using them :)